# Is the apparent superstrength and durability of the Djinn inherent?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel-2022

Within the 2022 *Ms. Marvel* TV show, in the third episode, "Destiny", there was a recent reveal that

> Kamala is descended from the [Clan Destine](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/ClanDestine), who are *Noori*, otherworldly beings exiled to Earth who are also known as Djinn.

During the episode, it's shown that

> the Djinn seem to have superhuman strength and durability, and are slow to age, if not unaging, traits which are so far not seen in Kamala or Muneeba, Kamala's mother, through whom the Djinn blood flows.

Is this because

> they are not of the first generation of Djinn?

Or is there something required to elicit those powers? I recognize that this might be covered in later episodes, but I also know that there's a decent amount of information that gets revealed in other sources, such as series creator tweets, and supplementary materials.

Answer (score 2):

As of the fifth episode, "Time and Again", we have seen Najma seemingly send her power on to Kamran, causing him to manifest glowing eyes and the ability to shoot energy blasts from his hands, so it seems that there is some finite amount of power, which can be passed along, presumably only to descendents with the right genetics. I will revise this answer if additional information comes about.

Comment: Though Najma herself didn't appear to have those abilities. It appears that pure Djinn and hybrid Djinn manifest their power in vastly different ways.

Comment: @OrangeDog this is addressed in the show - the Djinn can’t access the Noor energy because they are not properly adapted to life in the Earth dimension, and can’t access it through the Veil. Kamala is sufficiently close to a natural human - possibly because of genetics down the generations - that she can access Noor energy in this dimension, though the bracelet was required to unlock this ability, presumably by briefly linking her to the Noor dimension. (Najma has done something similar for Kamran, it seems, but this was only possible while the Veil was torn open.)